# GaussianFilter misbehave at large smoothing radii?

Tags: filtering, fourier-analysis

**Context**

Straight from the documentation of `GaussianFilter`, If one generates a time series and smooth it one gets

[image: time series]

```
res = Table[GaussianFilter[ts, r], {r, {10, 50, 100}}]; 
 ListLinePlot[Join[{ts}, res], 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "r = 10", "r = 50", "r = 100"}]
```

[image: time series and smoothed version]

(if you want to generate random data you could use
`data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, 0.01}]`)

**Problem**

But if I extend the smoothing range from the example   (admittedly in a rather unrealistic regime but bear with me)

```
data // Table[
   ListLinePlot[
    GaussianFilter[#, 10^R, Method -> "Gaussian", 
     Padding -> "Periodic"]], {R, 1, 4, 1/4}] &
```

[image: extension]

So you can see something rather odd which is that at larger smoothing radii  the curve become less smooth (i.e it shows more local extrema)!

**Question**

> Could you please confirm that this is a bug?

**Workaround**

FYI, a workaround is to use Fourier Filtering

```
fftIndgen[size_] := 2. Pi/ size ArrayPad[
   Range[0, Quotient[size, 2]], 
    {0, Quotient[size, 2] - 1}, 
   "ReflectedNegation"];
FourierGaussianFilter[data_, R_] := 
      InverseFourier[Fourier[data]*Exp[-1/2 R^2 
   fftIndgen[Length[data]]^2]] // Re // Chop
```

Then  with

[image]

I get

```
 data//Table[ListLinePlot[FourierGaussianFilter[#, 10^R]],
{R, 1, 4, 1/4}] &
```

[image]

> So in terms of diagnostic, one can visually see that 
>   `GaussianFilter` produces a growing number of extrema as a function of smoothing past a given threshold,  whereas `FourierGaussianFilter` does not.
>   IMHO the latter is behaving correctly in that regime, whereas the former does not. Note that this discrepancy  can be made quantitative e.g. for Gaussian random fields,  since there is a prediction for this number as a function of smoothing scale $R$ (i.e. it should scale like  $1/R$).

Comment: Looking at the decreasing scale on the vertical axes, it's not clear to me that the curves are becoming less smooth.  It does seem to me the series is approaching the mean of the data.  Just how is smoothness measured?

Comment: extrema identification

Comment: I kinda thought it was supposed to reduce the variation/variance of something or other.  But I don't know the formula.

Comment: As the Gaussian kernel gets wider and wider, it starts to matter what happens at the edges. That is -- what assumptions are being made outside the region of definition? There are two relevant parameters (from the Details section of the help file). One is Padding and the other is Standardized. If you don't like how the filter is currently handling edge effects, try changing these.

Comment: @bills thank you for your comment I have modified these and it makes no difference. I am concerned that mathematica s implementation is just plain wrong in that regime.

Comment: As Michael E2 said isn't it just the scale? If you fix the plot range then everything is smooth:data // Table[
   ListLinePlot[
    GaussianFilter[#, 10^R, Method -> "Gaussian", 
     Padding -> "Periodic"], PlotRange -> {Min[data], Max[data]}], {R, 1, 4, 
    1/4}] &

Comment: @demm  I beg to disagree the appearance of secondary maxima (whatever the amplitude) is not what I expect from gaussian smoothing.

Comment: It's not a bug.

Comment: As I understand it, it's not suppose to smooth, it's suppose to perform a linear convolution with a Gaussian kernel, which is basically a moving average with Gaussian weights.  What you get seems correct to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The code above which uses Fast Fourier transform also convolves with a Gaussian Kernel and does not yield extra bumps AFAIK.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But I am quite happy to agree with you that is a rather mute point given the baroque probed regime. May be I should add as a tag 'minor possible algorithmic improvement required' :-)

Comment: The Fourier approach is not quite the same thing, though, is it?  Look at `Exp[-1/2 R^2 fftIndgen[Length[data]]^2]` and you'll see you're basically truncating the Fourier series, which definitely smooths.  `GaussianFilter` seems to give a linear combination of random variables (conceptually); some jitter should be expected albeit with a lower variance as R increases. (I visualize it as a peak sliding along the periodically repeated data. As it does so, there are slight changes in the data being averaged. How could there not be noise?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am considering re-labeling this as a bug, because I have realised this problem has been a real nuisance for quite a while. I gave up using mathematica to produce simulation of smoothed Gaussian random field a few years ago because it was producing inconsistent results which I can now trace back to  GaussianFilter.

Comment: Well, I’m not an expert in this field. If I understand the math correctly, then the results of `GaussianFilter` are just what one should expect them to be. It is a discrete process and in a certain range of scales it appears to smooth the curve. What it really does (I think), is reduce the variance (which you can check it does). With periodic extrapolation, as the `r` increases the curve approaches a constant (the mean of the data) and the variance approaches zero; however, when you zoom in, the jitter from the discrete process is magnified, even though the changes in slope a relatively small.

Comment: I posted a question in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica) asking for others to help resolve this.

Comment: Does using `Padding -> "Fixed"` get you what you think you should get.  Using `Padding -> "Periodic"` is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's that the option `Padding -> "Periodic"` doesn't get the behavior you want.  Using `Padding -> "Fixed"` is probably what you want.

Here are the results using different scales for each radius:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, 0.001}]
data // Table[ListLinePlot[GaussianFilter[#, 10^R, Method -> "Gaussian", Padding -> "Fixed"],
    PlotLabel -> "R = " <> ToString[10.^R]], {R, 1, 4, 1/4}] &
```

[image: Separate scales]

Now with same scales:

[image: Same scales]